# Parallel vectors proof. Is it correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem: If $\overrightarrow{u} \neq \overrightarrow{0}$, then $\overrightarrow{v} = \alpha \overrightarrow{u}$ for some $\alpha$ if and only if $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$ are parallels.

This is my demonstration procedure:

$\overrightarrow{u}=(a_{1},b_{1})$

$\alpha\overrightarrow{u}=\alpha(a_{1},b_{1})$

$\alpha\overrightarrow{u}=(\alpha a_{1},\alpha b_{1})$

Then,

$\overrightarrow{v}=\alpha\overrightarrow{u}=(\alpha a_{1},\alpha b_{1})$

To check if these two vectors -$\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$- are parallels, we need to find and angle to 0 radians:

$\cos{\theta}=\frac{\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}}{|\overrightarrow{u}||\overrightarrow{v}|}$

Then

$\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}= \alpha a_{1}^{2} + \alpha b_{1}^{2}$

$|\overrightarrow{u}|=\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}$

$|\overrightarrow{v}|=\alpha\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}$

Therefore,

$\cos{\theta}= \frac{\alpha (a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2})}{\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}\alpha\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}}$

Once simplified, we have:

$\cos{\theta}=\frac{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}} {a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}=1$

And finally:

$\theta=\cos^{-1}{1}=0$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that if $v=\alpha u$, then the vectors are paralel. The proof you wrote is correct.

However, the statement says that the vectors are paralel **if and only if** $v=\alpha u$, which means you need to prove the other way around as well. You must show that if the vectors are paralel, then $v=\alpha u$.